# sympy plot3d and Min

Tags: sympy

I'm brand new to sympy, and what seems like it should be a simple example doesn't work for me. I'm running this in a fresh [Google colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/?utm_source=scs-index).

```py
import sympy
from sympy.plotting import plot3d 

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y') 
expr = sympy.Min(x, y)
print(expr)
expr.subs(x, .2).subs(y, .5)
```

So far so good. But now when I try to plot this using `plot3d`, I get an error:

```py
plot3d(expr, (x, -1, 1), (y, -1, 1))
```

results in `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. More strangely, when I change the expression to `Min(x, x)` it plots as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include all import statements in your code samples please?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the example with the complete imports (only 2).

Comment: You should do `expr = expr.subs(...)`

Comment: I think this is a bug that should be reported to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues